# Repeating a function: Check the return result and `not None`

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I' using a repeat function to repeat calling a function n times:

```
def repeat_function(sleep_time, times, expected_result, function, *args):
    for i in range(times):
        time_to_sleep = sleep_time/times
        sleep(time_to_sleep)
        result = function(*args)
        if result == expected_result:
            break
    return result
```

This works as a `polling` mechanism where it continuously calls a function till `expected_result` is received.

Now I need to use the same function (modify if needed) to check if result of a function is `not None` as well

something like:

```
repeat_function(4, 4, not None, func)
```

the problem is obviously `if result == expected_result` where I can not use `not None` as the `expected_result`
modifying the repeat function to do `if result == expected_result or result is expected_result` does not seems that logical as well (which may have side effects).

Is there any way to check if the return of a method is 
`not None` using `==` operator?

Any suggestions on how to address the problem is appreciated.

Comment: What about using `def repeat_function(sleep_time, times, UNexpected_result, function, *args)` and later just do something like `if isinstance(result, UNexpected_resultt): do something`? It would allow you to add multiple "unexpected" results as a tuple, because `isinstance` works also with: `isinstance(result, (None, int, float))` etc.

Comment: `None` resolves to `False`, and `not None` resolves to `True`. (Try typing `not None` in the python interpreter to see this). So it should suffice to pass in `True` in the expected_result argument. When the function returns a value that is `not None`, the `if result == expected_result` should equal `True`, and the loop will break. There's a caveat to this - that is, if the function returns a `bool` and could potentially return `False`. In that case, you'll need `if (result == expected_result) and (result is not False)`

Comment: @FrancoSolleza that doesn't seem to be the case. Result of the expression `2 == True` in python is `False` (so `if result == True` is `False`). for the other part I know I need to handle boolean functions properly, thanks for the heads up tho.

Comment: Of course. Missed that little misdeed. Back to the drawing board... amateur mistake.

Comment: @Nf4r Thanks for the suggestion but as mentioned, this is supposed to work as `polling` so it should break when the `expected_result` is met, but `isinstance` might be usefull here

Comment: Do you want to check for None in the same condition? If so try change your if condition to if result == expected_result and expected_result != None:

Comment: @jameswassinger I want to cover both `None` and `not None` in the same condition > to break the call if the `expected_result== None` or `expected_result== not None`. That depends on the use of the function (this is primarily being used for reading a DB, so for example it will take some time to get the result other than `None`). So I don't want to hardcode anything.

Comment: What is the point of using both a number of attempts along with a total timeout which is divided up by the number of attempts? Is that to make the API easier to use? i.e. "Try this function up to N times for no longer than X time or until the expected result is received?" That code smells wrong. If the total timeout is important, than it might be important to note that the code ignores the run time of the function being called.

Answer (score 3):

Pass a function that checks the expected result instead:

```
def repeat_function(sleep_time, times, is_expected_result, function, *args):
    for i in range(times):
        time_to_sleep = sleep_time/times
        sleep(time_to_sleep)
        result = function(*args)
        if is_expected_result(result):
            break
    return result
```

Call it like this:

```
repeat_function(4, 4, lambda x: x != None, func)
repeat_function(4, 4, lambda x: x == "expected_result", func)
repeat_function(4, 4, lambda x: x == 1234, func)
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to make it a bit more user-friendlier (if that makes sense!). I'm providing this function in a base class in a framework, and don't want to complicate the use.  But thanks for the answer.

Comment: This is by far the best approach. If you want your users to have an easy way to pass common kinds of functions, you could create your own `not_none` function that's part of this API, as well as an `is_equal_to(x)` function factory for the normal case (where they're testing for a single expected result). The nicest thing about this approach is that it lets your users pass in any sort of predicate they want, so if they want to test if the result is prime (or check the current phase of the moon, or whatever...) they can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's another go at it. My solution would be to define a class within your function:

```
class bool_check:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, value):
        if self.value or self.value == value:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Here's what a `bool_check` object would return when compared to another value. This by no means covers all instances but covers specifically your problem.

```
>>> t = bool_check(2)
>>> t == 2
True
>>> f = bool_check(None)
>>> f == True
False
>>> f = bool_check(False)
>>> f == True
False
>>> f == False
True
```

What you see is that when you compare `bool_check(None) == True`, you get `False`, which is what you want. When you compare `bool_check(2) == True`, you get `True`, which is also what you want.

Here's how it's used:

```
def repeat_function(sleep_time, times, expected_result, function, *args):
    for i in range(times):
        time_to_sleep = sleep_time/times
        sleep(time_to_sleep)
        result = function(*args)
        if bool_check(result) == expected_result:
            break
    return result
```

If you pass `True` into `expected_result`, then if `function(*args)` returns `None` then the check resolves to `False` and does not break. If it returns something, then the `__eq__` method of the `bool_check` class will return `True`.

This will work for your needs (I think) but won't cover all possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I'll take a deeper look (it may be a bit overcomplicated tho). The main values that I'm intersted in are the value returned by the function, `None` , and `not None`. But I can get something from here and use in the method itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a python function or use lambda expression, below is an example using the later:

```
def repeat_function(sleep_time, times, eval_result, function, *args):
    for i in range(times):
        time_to_sleep = sleep_time/times
        sleep(time_to_sleep)
        result = function(*args)
        if eval_result(result):
            break
    return result

eval_result = lambda result: result is not None
eval_result = lambda result: result == 4
```